# what does the --yes parameter at npm init mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, npm, init

What does the --yes parameter at npm init mean? 
I saw it [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#start-every-new-project-with-npm-init) and would like to know what it does exactly.
Is there a difference between --y and --yes?

Answer (score 14):

Doing `npm help init` prints out helpful information. Namely:

> If you invoke it with -f, --force, -y, or --yes, it will use only defaults and not prompt you for any options.